# How to show local notification after one day or 24 hours in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show local notification.

Below is my code.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings{

}
```

**In viewDidLoad()**

```
 defaultsnotification = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
 UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

  UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]; //Enter the time here in seconds.
  localNotification.alertBody = @"app Update Available";
  localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay; //Repeating instructions here.
  localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

By using this code notification is calling After a minute. But I need to call it after 24 hours.

How can I do That?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try changing: localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-20];

Comment: @AmitTandel No it is calling after minute Is anything I am doing wrong in code.

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding other UILocalNotification, from some other code. Search for UILocalNotification in your project.

Comment: @AmitTandel just one sure.

Answer (score 3):

Please update the following-

```
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(24*60*60)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
localNotification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
 notification.alertBody = @"24 hours passed since last visit :(";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Before that should dismiss all Notification....

Answer (score 0):

A duplicate question is there on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303413/iphone-daily-local-notifications)

[have a look at NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponents)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked before, Please go through this links and solve your problem.

[How to implement LocalNotification using objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087551/how-to-implement-localnotification-using-objective-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[How to schedule daily local push notification in iOS (ObjC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301621/how-to-schedule-daily-local-push-notification-in-ios-objc)

In addition, i have to say, if you are using iOS 10 then you have to register your local notification, it means you are permitting your notification to fire on a desired time.