# How to run for loop with delay of every 1 sec?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I am implementing alarm functionality for Apple's Watch application. So here I have to compare current time with user time and I have to get current time for every 1 sec, so that I have implemented the code like below but this is not working. Can any body please post appropriate code in Objective-C..

```
for (int i=0; i<86400; i++)
{  
    if ([getTotalDate isEqualToString:self.curTime])
        {
            NSLog(@"It's Alarm Time");
            [self presentControllerWithName:@"FifthViewController" context:nil];
            break;
        }
    else
        {
            NSLog(@"not alarm time");
            //[self currentTime];
        }
}
```

Comment: Cant you just use NSTimer for looping with delay time?

Comment: Why is the for loop being used ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set Local Notification for that particular time. And you should open `FifthViewController` in `didReceiveLocalNotification`. You can check the answer of following for how to use local notifications.

[How to implement LocalNotification using objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087551/how-to-implement-localnotification-using-objective-c)

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply ..actually I am implementing this for apple watch. So can you please suggest me how to implement alarm functionality through local notifications for Apple Watch..

Comment: here it was not mentioned so how I could know that it's apple watch program. You can check this link for apple watch notifications. https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchkit-actionable-notifications/

Answer (score -1):

Try using Stride

Here is an Apple provided solution (loop iteration over time constraints): [Swift control flow with Stride](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120)

Some users might want fewer tick marks in their UI. They could prefer one mark every 5 minutes instead. Use the stride(from:to:by:) function to skip the unwanted marks.

```
let minuteInterval = 5
for tickMark in stride(from: 0, to: minutes, by: minuteInterval) {
    // render the tick mark every 5 minutes (0, 5, 10, 15 ... 45, 50, 55)
}



let hours = 12
let hourInterval = 3
for tickMark in stride(from: 3, through: hours, by: hourInterval) {
    // render the tick mark every 3 hours (3, 6, 9, 12)
}
```

Comment: @Tj3n - Yes dear, I know, but OP has added a tag `swift` and he may use Swift code in Objective-C project also. And apple may not have provided this solution in Objective-C. So if OP can inject Swift code in Objective-C project, then this can be helpful to him.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply.. Actually I am developing in Objective C, So is this stride  is there in objective c also? if yes can you please post code in objective c..